# Correct way of passing instance argument

Tags: javascript, oop, design-patterns

Suppose I manage pizzera and I want to know when the first order of the day arrive.

I have two classes: `Orders` (storing orders) and `Events`. I am invoking a function `getCurrentEvents()` which checks if the order is the first order of the day.

**Q:** When should I pass the `Orders` argument to `getCurrentEvents()`? Moreover, could you give me a hint how's this topic called so I can read more about similiar design problems?

## 1st method

pass `Orders` while creating `Events` instance, use it directly in function

```
class Pizzeria {
  constructor() {
    this.orders = new Orders()
    // pass Orders here
    this.events = new Events(this.orders)
  }

  getCurrentEvents() {
    this.events.getCurrentEvents();
  }
}

class Events {
  constructor(orders) {
    this.orders = orders;
  }

  getCurrentEvents() {
    this.firstOderOfTheDay();
  }

  firstOrderOfTheDay() {
    ...do something with this.orders
  }
}
```

## 2nd method

again pass `Orders` while creating `Events` instance but pass it to the function

```
class Pizzeria {
  constructor() {
    this.orders = new Orders()
    this.events = new Events(this.orders)
  }

  getCurrentEvents() {
    this.events.getCurrentEvents();
  }
}

class Events {
  constructor(orders) {
    this.orders = orders;
  }

  getCurrentEvents() {
    // pass Orders here
    this.firstOderOfTheDay(this.orders);
  }

  firstOrderOfTheDay({ orders }) {
    ...do something with passed orders
  }
}
```

## 3rd method

pass it after `Events` instance is created

```
class Pizzeria {
  constructor() {
    this.orders = new Orders()
    this.events = new Events()
  }

  getCurrentEvents() {
    // pass Orders here
    this.events.getCurrentEvents(this.orders);
  }
}

class Events {
  getCurrentEvents(orders) {
    this.firstOderOfTheDay(orders);
  }

  firstOrderOfTheDay({ orders }) {
    ...do something with orders
  }
}
```

Comment: Read up on object-oriented-design in general.  The question to ask yourself is "how long does events need to know about orders?" - does the events list need to know about all of the orders?  Or just needs to know about orders just once?

Comment: I think that only Orders should be able to determine the firstOderOfTheDay

Comment: It must know about all the orders all the time, not only once, so `getgetCurrentEvents()` could update status e.g. `firstOrderOfTheDay`, `BiggestOrder`, `MostExpensiveOrder` etc. Also, thank you about the suggestion.

Comment: I think of 'events' as a transitory object - only there to show that an event has happened. The effect of the event is to change some status - maybe add (or cancel) and order. It seems that you are maintaining a record of the events (nothing wrong in that) but can't decide which object list should store the order information.

Comment: You need to clarify, what the `Events` class represents. In the first example, i think these two classes are too tightly coupled. The second example makes no sense at all; why would you need to pass `this.something` to a method of `this`? Why doesn't this method access that data directly? And to your third example, again, what is `Events`? Why does `Pizzeria` need to know it? `firstOrderOfTheDay` seems to me like a method of the `Orders` object, or a static method that takes an Orders object. So why is it a method of `Events`?

Comment: And `getCurrentEvents` seems the wrong approach. An event occurs *somewhen*, you should implement a listener pattern e.g. `events.on("order", order => ...)`

Comment: @Thomas **2nd method** indeed looks like nonsense, thanks for pointing that out, I can rule out that method. Maybe class should be named `Status` instead of `Events` and based on each status I could fire some proper `Events` e.g - if `firstOrder` is `true`, let's make the price 10% off. If I were going for **3rd method** I should use static method, there's no point in creating separate instance, is it?

Comment: @YolaXi your last comment made me confused. Do you want to make the price 10% off for the first order ever in the pizzeria? the first order of the day or the first order of a client? Those are different things. It would be easier to help you with an adequate approach if we know what do you really want to do.